# Initialize a Sympy row vector without transpose

Tags: sympy

Initializing a vector using `sympy.Matrix([1, 2, 3, 4])` creates a (4, 1) matrix unlike in numpy where it would be (1, 4). Doing `sympy.Matrix([[1], [2], [3], [4]])` initializes the same (4, 1) matrix. So I have to do `sympy.Matrix([1, 2, 3, 4]).T` to get a row vector.
Is there a way to do it without a transpose?
I couldn't find anything about row vectors or (1, n) matrices in the documentation.

Comment: What's wrong with using `.T`?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin it seemed like a hack rather than an idiomatic way to do it

Comment: I don't think it's a "hack". You can write the code how you like though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs

```
To make it easy to make column vectors, a list 
of elements is considered to be a column vector.
```

Row vector only needs one extra set of []

```
sympy.Matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Don't use `np.matrix` as a model for anything.  It was a stop gap addition for wayward MATLAB programers :)

more usage examples at

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html